# Getting 404 Not Found while trying to run Jenkins on Tomcat on MAC OS

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, installation

Steps:

1. Downloaded jenkins.war 2.263.3 LTS from this page: https://www.jenkins.io/download/jenkins.war
2. Downloaded tomcat tar.gz version 10 from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi
3. Extracted Tomcat
4. ./bin/startup.sh and verify http://localhost:8080 is ok
5. Move jenkins.war to webapps folder
6. try http://localhost:8080/jenkins

I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/jenkins] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.2
```

I am on MAC OS Catalina 10.15.7

```
java --version
java 11.0.7 2020-04-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I see this in the Tomcat logs:

````
==> localhost.2021-02-03.log <==
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
        ... 51 more
03-Feb-2021 12:00:07.369 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
03-Feb-2021 12:00:07.648 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
03-Feb-2021 12:00:07.648 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
03-Feb-2021 12:00:07.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@65ee756a')

==> localhost_access_log.2021-02-03.txt <==
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:47:30 -0800] "GET /asf-logo-wide.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 27235
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:47:30 -0800] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:47:30 -0800] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:47:30 -0800] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:47:30 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:47:35 -0800] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 404 758
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:48:40 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11163
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:50:44 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11163
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:50:47 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11163
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:11:50:53 -0800] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 404 758
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:12:01:12 -0800] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 404 758
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:12:01:18 -0800] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 404 758
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Feb/2021:12:01:25 -0800] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 404 758```
````